# Convert epoch to human-readable date to normal date in unix command

Tags: shell-script

I have a file with below data, trying to convert first field values to date, however second field is missing

```
cat memoey-total.csv
1700561388,277126765312
1700561647,277126765312
1700561811,277126765312
1700562945,277126765312
1700563689,277126765312

awk '{$1 = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", substr($1,1,10))} 1' memoey-total.csv

20231121100948
20231121101407
20231121101651
20231121103545
20231121104809
20231121110003
20231121111003
20231121112003
```

I am able to convert to required format but how to get second field also in the output?

Comment: I'd recommend (if you have the possibility to modify it as you wish) to instead output : iso8601's dates : YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS+hh:mm ( "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z" in gnu date format) : they are the best portable date formats and are easy to "parse" by both humans and scripts, and having the timezone shift is crucial to include, imo (otherwise the date is really only known with a +-12h accuracy...)

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell AWK (Gawk, technically, since you’re using `strftime`) to use commas as field separators, for input and output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," } {$1 = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", substr($1,1,10))} 1' memoey-total.csv
20231121110948,277126765312
20231121111407,277126765312
20231121111651,277126765312
20231121113545,277126765312
20231121114809,277126765312
```

With [Gawk 5.3.0 or later](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2023-11/msg00000.html), you can use [CSV mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comma-Separated-Fields.html) (`--csv`) instead (this is also available in the latest version of [The One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk), but the latter doesn’t have `strftime`).

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Kitt

Comment: @yugenreddy if this is the best answer for you please remember to accept it ✔

Comment: Looks like 5.3 has just been released. I find that its `--csv` removes `\r`s that are followed by `\n`s even when they occur within a field btw. To use `--csv`, here you'd also need `-i /path/to/tocsv.awk` and use `tocsv_rev()` from there to format the output as csv.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -pe 's/\d+/strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime($&))/e'
```

Will convert the first sequence of digits to the corresponding local time in that YYYYmmddHHMMSS format.

Replace `localtime`  with `gmtime` or prefix the command with `TZ=UTC0`  if you want the UTC time there in place of the local time¹.

---

<sup>¹ beware that since that format doesn't  specify the timezone  offset, it's ambiguous in timezones that do DST as two different epoch times can give the same timestamp. For instance, both `1698539456` and `1698543056` yield the same `20231029013056` timestamp in the Europe/London timezone</sup>